# Scala PartialFunction with isDefinedA and apply not working

Tags: scala, partialfunction

I am new in Scala, i was trying PartialFunctions, is this correct way to test functionality, as some tutorials followed this to work, but not working for me?

code:

```
object MyScalaApp extends App {
def try29{
    val r = new PartialFunction[Int, Int]  
    { 
        def isDefinedAt(q: Int) = q < 0 // Applying isDefinedAt method  
        def apply(q: Int) = 12 * q // Applying apply method 
    }        
    val rr = new PartialFunction[Double, Double]  
    { 
        def isDefinedAt(q: Double) = {q < 0}
        def apply(q: Double) = 12 * q 
    }

    println(r(1))
    println(r(2))        
    println(rr(-1))
    println(rr(-2))
  }
  }
  try29
}
```

output:

```
12
24
-12.0
-24.0
```

Why `apply` get call when its not matching first condition?
When I write `def isDefinedAt(q: Int) = q != 0` it gives `println(r(0))` as output `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html):

> It is the responsibility of the caller to call `isDefinedAt` before calling `apply`...

Let's try your `r()` Partial Function in a context where `isDefinedAt()` is called automatically.

```
val r = new PartialFunction[Int, Int] {
  def isDefinedAt(q: Int) = q < 0
  def apply(q: Int) = 12 * q
}
List(4,-3,22,-9,0).collect(r)
//res0: List[Int] = List(-36, -108)
```

Seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly what you asked, but I think it is worth mentioning the existence of [`applyOrElse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html#applyOrElse%5BA1%3C:A,B1%3E:B%5D(x:A1,default:A1=%3EB1):B1). if later on you plan to write code such as:

```
if(r.isDefinedAt(1)) r(1) else 10
```

It is better to use `applyOrElse`, as elaborated in the docs:

> Note that expression `pf.applyOrElse(x, default)` is equivalent to
>
> ```
> if(pf isDefinedAt x) pf(x) else default(x)
> ```
>
> except that `applyOrElse` method can be implemented more efficiently. For all partial function literals the compiler generates an applyOrElse implementation which avoids double evaluation of pattern matchers and guards. This makes applyOrElse the basis for the efficient implementation for many operations and scenarios.